# Knockout.js and Twitterfeed updating page with intervals

Tags: twitter, knockout.js, pageload

I am currently trying to update my twitter feed every 1 minute for example.
But I have no idea how to.

This is my ViewModel:

```
var savedLists = ['NielsenRamon', 'Wouter_Willaert', 'AWT_Centric'];

var twitterListModel = function(list) {
    this.savedLists = ko.observableArray(list);
    this.currentTweets = ko.observableArray([]);

    ko.computed(function() {
        twitterApi.getTweetsForUsers(savedLists, this.currentTweets);
    }, this).extend({ throttle: 1 });
}

ko.applyBindings(new twitterListModel(savedLists));
```

I'm using a very minified version of this :http://knockoutjs.com/examples/twitter.html
the API i use is also the same.

What I want is that the bindings on my html page get updated every minute for example without refreshing my page. For example: when someone tweets. That tweet get displayed on the page after 1 minute without refreshing the page.

Is this possible the way I am working now?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `setInterval` that calls `twitterApi.getTweetsForUsers` every minute.

Something like:  `setInterval(function() { twitterApi.getTweetsForUsers(savedLists, twitterListModel.currentTweets); }, 60000);`

If the calls can take a while though, then you might want to modify the `twitterApi` sample code and use a `setTimeout` in the callback from the actual twitter API calls that reschedules itself with a new `setTimeout`.

Comment: I allready tried that but the problem is that it doesn't update my bindings. Any ideas on that? I think it's something to do with Knockout.js.

Comment: Maybe you can get your code into a jsFiddle.  Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ATAr5/

Comment: I tried out my old code again with the same structure as yours and it looks like it takes a while to pick up the data from Twitter! So yeah I just needed patience. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I just need him to return only the last 6 tweets. Any idea on that?

Comment: You would want to take your own copy of the twitterApi.js file and modify this line:  `var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=";`  You would want the `100` to be `6`.